# WooCommerce: Show or hide Out of Stock button depending upon stock conditions

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, hide, show

I've got a button that should appear depending upon whether or not a product or one of its variations (if it's a variable product) is out of stock. If it's in stock, don't display it.

Been playing with lots of scripts but nothing seems to stick. Here's where I am currently at:

Example: https://bplsource.com/product/techniglove-12%e2%80%b3-nitrile-usp-797-white-powder-free/

HTML:

```
<div class=\"woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button\">\n\t<p class=\"stock out-of-stock\">Out of stock, Can be backordered<\/p>
```

PHP with JavaScript:

```php
// Add Custom Content Before 'Add To Cart' Button On Product Page
function my_content() {
    global $product;
    
    // Check if the product or any of its variations is out of stock
    $is_out_of_stock = false;
    
    if ($product->get_manage_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0) {
        $is_out_of_stock = true;
    }
    
    if ($product->is_type('variable') && !$is_out_of_stock) {
        foreach ($product->get_children() as $variation_id) {
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            if ($variation && $variation->get_manage_stock() && $variation->get_stock_quantity() <= 0) {
                $is_out_of_stock = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Display the out-of-stock message if needed
    if ($is_out_of_stock) {
        echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock, Can be backordered</p>';
    }
    
    // Enqueue JavaScript to dynamically show or hide the out-of-stock message
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var isOutOfStock = <?php echo $is_out_of_stock ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
            if (!isOutOfStock) {
                $('.stock.out-of-stock').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Add the action hook only once
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:-**

You can simply use **CSS** for this.

```
.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart.variations_button.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled .stock.out-of-stock {
    display: block;
}

.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart.variations_button.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled .stock.out-of-stock {
    display: none;
}
```

This CSS rule will hide the "Out of stock, Can be backordered" if the Add to Cart Button is Disabled.

**Solution 2:-**

The JavaScript that you are "enqueuing" directly, is being added to DOM AFTER the "Ready" event is triggered. So your function will never run as it is listening for the ready trigger.

Instead, you need to update the script as follows:-

```
<script>
    var isOutOfStock = <?php echo $is_out_of_stock ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
    if (!isOutOfStock) {
        $('.stock.out-of-stock').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, neither of these ideas worked. The first one hid both buttons and then if you selected a variant, the out of stock button would appear. Select a variant that is in stock and then the In Stock button appears above the out of stock button. Solution 2? Out of stock appears no matter what and then if you select an in stock variant, the in stock appears above the out of stock.